# How to solve StandfordOpenNLP error

Tags: nlp, lemmatization

I have downloaded StanfordOpenNLP and try to use its lemmatiser. But it gives me an error as below,

> Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Can anyone please tell me how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also tried to install that but got the same error. This is because library has compiled with JDK 1.8 but u may try to run it with a lower version than 1.8. To solve this

1. download the latest jdk version from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)
2. go to

> C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.x\etc\netbeans.conf

and Change the following line to point it where your java installation is :

> netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8xxxxx"

You may need Administrator privileges to edit netbeans.conf.Then Try to run the program.